# Idle games and web workers for background tabs

Tags: javascript, web-worker

I've been working on an idle/incremental game in my free time.

The main game loop function gets called many times a second using setInterval.

Since chrome (and probably other browsers) throttle function calls to 1 per second, my game loop doesn't properly update the right amount of times so now im looking into web workers.

After reading through the WebWorkers documentation on MDN, i still have a question on how to properly implement the web worker.

My current idea is to detect when the user swaps tabs (`onblur`):

1. Pause the setInterval for gameLoop
2. Post a message to my worker with the current game state
3. Within the worker, continue computing the game state
4. When tab gets refocused, send message back and update game state with message
5. unpause setInterval and terminate worker.

Would this be the right way to use the Web Worker?

Thanks!

-EDIT-

Some additional info, my game is an idle game similar to cookie clicker so there isnt any position tracking.

A very brief idea of something that is within my `gameLoop` is a function call to `gainResources(resourcePerSecond/gameTickRate)`.

Comment: What is it you have to update each tick? Positions? Lots of collisions? Others? The best in a browser is to not rely on your tick to fire at any rate. Instead calculate "by how much" each object has evolved since last tick. This way the tab can be paused, your game's logic will still be "alive". Even your web worker will get throttled anyway.

Comment: I updated the original post. What the game needs to update is just stuff like `resourceAmount`, `questProgress`, etc. I've also seen other people mentioning tracking time between updates and do stuff accordingly but I thought web workers would be a better solution.

Comment: They won't. Soon browsers will throttle them just like UI thread. The only way then would be to keep something preventing the tab from being throttled at all (there are a few ways), but this also means that your tab will eat a lot of resources for something as simple as a multiplication and that's not cool for trees.

Comment: Hmmm okay then. That makes sense. I guess ill implement the delta diff method instead and calculate resources based on `timeSinceLastUpdate`. Thanks for your input.

Comment: This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MCi6AZMkxcU) is just what you want and this [gist with workable solution](https://gist.github.com/jakearchibald/cb03f15670817001b1157e62a076fe95) from same video. Worth watching. Very informative

Answer (score 1):

My solution to stopping background tabs from throttling is to calculate the difference in time between each loop, and use that value to calculate how much things should've changed, assuming your loop updates things like resource amounts.

Example -

```
function loop() {
    let now = Date.now();
    let diff = now - Game.lastUpdate;
    Game.lastUpdate = now;
    // diff is now the exact amount of ms since loop has been called.
}
```

This way you are also sure to give an accurate production rate as setInterval doesn't call functions at exactly the same interval every time.